# Initialize pointer to structure - compiler warning

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, g++, warnings

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
   int factorX;
   double coefficient;
};

int main()
{
   test firstTest = {1, 7.5}; //that's ok

   test *secondTest = new test;
   *secondTest = {8, 55.2}; // issue a compiler warning

}
```

I don't understand why the compiler issues the following warning:

```
test2.cpp:13:33: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
test2.cpp:13:33: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

I know that in C++11 I can omit the assignment operator but that's not the case.
I am using g++ 4.7.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `test` structure is an aggregate. While initialization of an [aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) with the braces syntax is supported in C++98, assignment is not.

Here, what is really going on is that the compiler invokes the implicitly generated move-assignment operator, which takes a `test&&` as its input. In order to make this call legal, the compiler will have to convert `{8, 55.2}` into an instance of `test` by constructing a temporary from it, then move-assign `*secondTest` from this temporary.

This behavior is supported only in C++11, which is why the compiler is telling you that you have to compile with the `-std=c++11` option.

Answer (score 2):

Since first is initialization and second is assignment. You can initialize simple struct this way in C++98, but not assign.

8.5.1/1

> An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or pro-
> tected non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

8.5.1/2

> When an aggregate is initialized the initializer can contain an initializer-clause consisting of a brace-
> enclosed, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses for the members of the aggregate, written in increasing
> subscript or member order.

But second construction calls `operator =` of class, since you have no user-defined copy c-tor, default copy c-tor will be called, in C++11 with expression in `{}` can be constructed object of needed type, but not in C++98.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what you need to do, you need to add `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to the command line when compiling your program. It is a C++11 feature and you have to enable it:

```
 test2.cpp:13:33: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As Andy was saying it is a C++11 feature to use an implicitly generated move function on the temporary which is created from `{8, 55.2}`, which is what you have in the second case.

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But what's the difference between the two initializations? Without "secondTest", the compiler don't ask me to use the -std=c++11 flag and I can't understand why.

Comment: @Toshko: The difference is that the second one is not an initialization: it is an assignment